# PHP ORDER BY with a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner in php and am having some trouble changing the ORDER BY with a variable. I have tried to research and get it figured out, but with no luck. I am wanting the form name "filter" to pass the option name into the php variable "filter" then order by the "filter" variable in the mysql select query. What am I missing here?

### Here is the code:

#### per recommendations I have edited the code and posted the edits.

```
    <center><h2> Saved Weapons List</h2>

<form name="filter" action="" method="post">
    <select name="filter">
        <option value="weaponType"> Weapon Type</option>
        <option value="weaponCategory"> Weapon Category</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</center>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$filter = $_POST['filter'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM weapons ORDER BY '{$filter}' desc");



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
$row['masterwork'] = ( intval( $row['masterwork']) == 1) ? "Yes" : "No";
  echo "<center>";
  echo "<table border='1' class='display'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Name: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Creator: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['creator'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Category: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Sub-Category: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponSubCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Cost: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['costAmount'] . " " . $row['costType'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Damage(S): </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['damageS'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Damage(M): </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['damageM'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Critical: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['critical'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Range Increment: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['rangeIncrement'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weight: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Type: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponType'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Masterwork: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['masterwork'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Attributes: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['attributes'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Special Abilities: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['specialAbilities'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Additional Info: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['additionalInfo'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have the _constant_ `filter` defined, or did you actually mean `$_POST['filter']` (note the quotes)?

Comment: Well the filter will change based on the selected option in the html form on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple updates (mainly for security reasons. as @Wrikken wrote in the comments -  your code is ASKING for injections).

First. Change option values to something (digits may be), and then check it in PHP.

```
    <option value="filter1"> Weapon Type</option>
    <option value="filter2"> Weapon Category</option>
```

And then filter it in PHP

```
$filter = 'weaponType';

switch($_POST["filter"]) {
case 'filter2': $filter = 'weaponCategory'; break;
}
```

Second. if `$filter` set - run the query...

```
if (isset($filter)) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM weapons ORDER BY " . $filter . " desc");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    /* output */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this did it! One more thing if you are up for it. Now when I initially load the page, it displays nothing. Once I select a filter and press submit it does display properly. How could I get the page to load a sort of default query when you first go to it?

Comment: in that case you can just set `$filter` to a default value ( let's say weaponType). `$filter = 'filter1';` And so all requests will be ordered either by default value or by passed patamether.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by the name of the column, not by the value of the variable.

Try:

```
$filter = $_POST['filter'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM weapons ORDER BY `{$filter}` desc");
```

Comment: For a clear disambiguation of MySQL quotes read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: After changing to this the results went blank after the form.

Comment: Make damn sure you whitelist that `$filter` against a known good list. otherwise it's begging for sql injection.

Comment: Also, the correct usage is `<option value="...">...</option>` and NOT `<option name="...">...</option>`.

Comment: @Aldentec there is some kind of a PHP error. I've changed to `$_POST['filter']`. You should turn on error reporting and debug more. On a separate note it is very useful to use prepared statements, to use ORM and generally to always escape every outside value which reaches the database.

Comment: I changed the options to value="..." still no luck

Comment: @Aldentec Try with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning. This way you could see the error.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev Please excuse my ignorance but what am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: @Aldentec As I mentioned above, the blank page is most probably caused by a PHP error which is not reported. By turning on the error reporting you would actually see where it the error during the execution and could fix it yourself. This has nothing to do with the SQL query though.

Comment: Oh the page was not completely blank. Basically just the results of the mysql query were not showing up. Sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47359/discussion-between-haralan-dobrev-and-aldentec)